# JMeter: Why script recorded in Windows does not work on Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, plugins, scripting, jmeter

I have recorded script in Windows (JMeter 3.0) and since Windows is not handling large number of User, I am trying to utilize the same script in Ubuntu (JMeter 2.3.4) but that shows error popup as:

**Error in Test Plan. See Log File**

Log file has following message:

```html
2016/08/04 11:36:02 INFO  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_IN 
2016/08/04 11:36:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2009 The Apache Software Foundation 
2016/08/04 11:36:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Version 2.3.4 
2016/08/04 11:36:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.version=1.6.0_38 
2016/08/04 11:36:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.vm.name=OpenJDK Server VM 
2016/08/04 11:36:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.name=Linux 
2016/08/04 11:36:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.arch=i386 
2016/08/04 11:36:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.version=3.5.0-54-generic 
2016/08/04 11:36:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: file.encoding=UTF-8 
2016/08/04 11:36:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Default Locale=English (India) 
2016/08/04 11:36:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (India) 
2016/08/04 11:36:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeterHome=/usr/share/jmeter 
2016/08/04 11:36:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: user.dir  =/home/webwerks 
2016/08/04 11:36:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: PWD       =/home/webwerks 
2016/08/04 11:36:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: IP: 127.0.1.1 Name: BT-R1P7 FullName: BT-R1P7 
2016/08/04 11:36:02 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loaded icon properties from org/apache/jmeter/images/icon.properties 
2016/08/04 11:36:04 INFO  - jmeter.util.BSFTestElement: Registering JMeter version of JavaScript engine as work-round for BSF-22 
2016/08/04 11:36:05 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: No response parsers defined: text/html only will be scanned for embedded resources 
2016/08/04 11:36:05 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler: Maximum connection retries = 10 
2016/08/04 11:36:05 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler: Connection and read timeouts are available on this JVM 
2016/08/04 11:36:06 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are END times 
2016/08/04 11:36:06 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1 
2016/08/04 11:36:20 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Default base=/home/webwerks 
2016/08/04 11:36:20 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Loading file: /home/webwerks/Downloads/Abhijeet.jmx 
2016/08/04 11:36:20 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base=/home/webwerks/Downloads 
2016/08/04 11:36:20 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2 
2016/08/04 11:36:20 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8 
2016/08/04 11:36:20 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file version 697317 
2016/08/04 11:36:20 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 2.1 
2016/08/04 11:36:20 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: All converter versions present and correct 
2016/08/04 11:36:20 ERROR - jmeter.save.SaveService: Conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
---- Debugging information ----
message             : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/HTTPSamplerProxy
line number         : 40
------------------------------- : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
---- Debugging information ----
message             : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/HTTPSamplerProxy
line number         : 40
-------------------------------
message             : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
---- Debugging information ----
message             : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/HTTPSamplerProxy
line number         : 40
-------------------------------
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:81)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/HTTPSamplerProxy
line number         : 40
------------------------------- 
2016/08/04 11:36:20 WARN  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Unexpected error java.lang.Exception: Error in TestPlan - see log file
 at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.insertLoadedTree(Load.java:153)
 at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:108)
 at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doAction(Load.java:89)
 at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:80)
 at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:42)
 at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:59)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:226)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:685)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:96)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:646)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:644)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:655)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:275)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:200)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:190)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:185)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:177)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:138)

2016/08/04 11:37:13 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Loading file: /home/webwerks/Downloads/Abhijeet.jmx 
2016/08/04 11:37:13 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base=/home/webwerks/Downloads 
2016/08/04 11:37:13 ERROR - jmeter.save.SaveService: Conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
---- Debugging information ----
message             : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/HTTPSamplerProxy
line number         : 40
------------------------------- : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
---- Debugging information ----
message             : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/HTTPSamplerProxy
line number         : 40
-------------------------------
message             : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
---- Debugging information ----
message             : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/HTTPSamplerProxy
line number         : 40
-------------------------------
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:81)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/HTTPSamplerProxy
line number         : 40
------------------------------- 
2016/08/04 11:37:13 WARN  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Unexpected error java.lang.Exception: Error in TestPlan - see log file
 at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.insertLoadedTree(Load.java:153)
 at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:108)
 at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doAction(Load.java:89)
 at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:80)
 at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:42)
 at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:59)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:226)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:685)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:96)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:646)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:644)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:655)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:275)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:200)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:190)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:185)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:177)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:138)

2016/08/04 11:37:50 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Loading file: /home/webwerks/Downloads/Abhijeet.jmx 
2016/08/04 11:37:50 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base=/home/webwerks/Downloads 
2016/08/04 11:37:50 ERROR - jmeter.save.SaveService: Conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
---- Debugging information ----
message             : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/HTTPSamplerProxy
line number         : 40
------------------------------- : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
---- Debugging information ----
message             : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/HTTPSamplerProxy
line number         : 40
-------------------------------
message             : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
---- Debugging information ----
message             : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/HTTPSamplerProxy
line number         : 40
-------------------------------
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:81)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/HTTPSamplerProxy
line number         : 40
------------------------------- 
2016/08/04 11:37:50 WARN  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Unexpected error java.lang.Exception: Error in TestPlan - see log file
 at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.insertLoadedTree(Load.java:153)
 at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:108)
 at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doAction(Load.java:89)
 at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:80)
 at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:42)
 at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:59)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:226)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:685)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:96)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:646)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:644)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:655)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:275)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:200)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:190)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:185)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:177)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
```

Does this happen due to JMeter versions mismatch in both OS? If that is true, I have earlier utilized Script in Windows which was created in Ubuntu.

Note: Script has all inbuilt features only, have not added any extra plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter 2.3.4 is 7-years old, a lot of stuff has changed since then. Each new version brings some incompatible changes. You need to upgrade JMeter on your Ubuntu system.

1. Download latest [Java SDK from Oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) (currently it's Java 8) and extract it somewhere, i.e. to `/opt/java`
2. Download latest [JMeter from Apache website](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) (currently it's JMeter 3.0) and extract it somewhere, i.e to `/opt/jmeter`
3. Set `JAVA_HOME` variable to `/opt/java` (or whatever folder you chose in step 1)

   ```
   JAVA_HOME=/opt/java && export JAVA_HOME
   ```
4. Add Java SDK "bin" folder to system PATH

   ```
   PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH && export PATH
   ```
5. Launch JMeter (make sure you launch JMeter 3.0, not the one which comes with Ubuntu) like

   ```
   cd /opt/jmeter/bin
   ./jmeter
   ```

I would also recommend considering upgrading to 64-bit operating system and JDK as you won't be able to use > 4 GB (usually even less) of heap space hence the load you will be able to create will be very limited. See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article for more detailed explanation on this and other hints.